# Different outputs when stating return or not

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and I am trying to learn it by writing a simple program to check if given a string each open paranthesis has its own closed parenthesis.
For example for the string "{{ssss{{}}}}}" the answer should be false.
The code I am using is the following:

```
package recfun
import common._
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

object Main{
def main(args: Array[String]) {
 println(balance("{{ssss{{}}}}}".toList))
}

def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {

 val openParentheses : List[Char] = List('(','{','[')
 val matchingParentheses = Map(
   '}'-> '{',
   ']'->'[',
   ')'->'(');

 val openParenthesesFound: Stack[Char] = Stack[Char]()

 for (letter <- chars) {
   if (openParentheses.contains(letter)) openParenthesesFound.push(letter)
   else if (matchingParentheses.contains(letter)) {
     if (openParenthesesFound.isEmpty || !openParenthesesFound.head.equals(matchingParentheses(letter))) return false
     else
       openParenthesesFound.pop
   }
 }

 if (openParenthesesFound.nonEmpty) false else true
 }
}
```

However, in the lines

```
if (openParenthesesFound.isEmpty || !openParenthesesFound.head.equals(matchingParentheses(letter))) return false
else
  openParenthesesFound.pop
```

if I remove "return" as suggested by IntellijIdea the program fails and I get wrong answer: True.

Can anybody help me exaplaining me why it happens so? I am probably missing something. 
Also, does anyone have a better solution for this kind of task?

Thank you very much for the help,
Giovanni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij is wrong. Obviously, removing return statement changes the logic of your function.
Perhaps, what it means to tell you is that using return statements in scala is frowned upon in general. It is usually better to come up with a solution avoiding it. Same goes for mutable state actually ...

Something like this is one of the possibilities:

```
  val parens = "{[(" zip "}])" toMap

  object OpenP {
     def unapply(c: Char) = parens.keys.find(_ == c)
  }
  object CloseP {
     def unapply(c: Char) = parens.values.find(_ == c)
  }

  @tailrec
  def balanced(s: List[Char], ps: List[Char] = Nil): Boolean = (ps, s) match {
     case (stack, Nil) => stack.isEmpty
     case (p :: stack, CloseP(c) :: tail) => c == parens(p) && balanced(tail, stack)
     case (stack, OpenP(p) :: tail) => balanced(tail, p :: stack)
     case (stack, c :: tail) => balanced(tail, stack)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code flow will substantially change depending on whether you use `return` in the middle of the `for` comprehension here.

If you use `return`, your `balance` method will exit with `false` the first time you end up in that code path, which seems to be what you want (return `false` when you encounter the first mismatched parenthesis, since you require that none exist).

If you don't use `return`, only the containing `if-else` block will evaluate to false (remember, everything in Scala is an expression) instead of exiting the whole method. Since you aren't assigning it or checking it, your check actually does pretty much nothing, you will loop the whole thing through, and the last statement returns `true`. So you need the `return` if you want to solve this problem in this manner.

However, Scala encourages functional programming style without mutable state (such as your `Stack` here). The simplest way to solve this problem that way would probably be recursion and using an accumulator to store the intermediate parenthesis stack - this way you don't need mutable state (`var`s or mutable collections). And you avoid using explicit `return`s (which is encouraged - also probably the reason why your IDE is notifying you about its use) since a method implicitly returns its last statement as its value and this is often simple to achieve with a recursive approach.